# C - Synchronizing Errors using Semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, fork, semaphore

here is my code where there's a FATHER that creates 15 processes using fork() and then he starts a timer. After the creation, all the child must interact with themselves (not with the father) until the timer stops. After that, they Unlock the semaphore, the father starts his duty and then terminate. I got some problems with the semaphores. When the child have the Lock, the program waits forever.

```
#define NUM_SEMS 2 //number of semaphores
#define PADRE 0 //father semaphore
#define ALUNNI 1 //child semaphore
#define POP_SIZE 15 //number of child

/*more defines*/
/*shared memory initialization*/

/* Create a shared memory area */
   mem_Id = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(*corso), 0600);
   TEST_ERROR;
   shm_id = mem_Id;
   /* Attach the shared memory to a pointer */
   corso = shmat(mem_Id, NULL, 0);
   TEST_ERROR;

   corso->cur_idx = 0;   /* init first counter */
   shm_print_stats(2, mem_Id);

   /* Create a semaphore to synchronize the start of all child
    * processes */
printf("Creo SEMAFORI\n");

   sem_Id = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, NUM_SEMS, 0600);
   TEST_ERROR;
   /* Sem 0 to syncronize the start of child processes */
   semctl(sem_Id, 0, SETVAL, 0);


//  TEST_ERROR;

#ifdef SHMEMORY
   semctl(sem_Id, 1, SETVAL, 1); //puoi disattivare il semaforo
#endif  

   /* Initialize the common fields */
   sops.sem_num = 0;     /* check the 0-th semaphore */
   sops.sem_flg = 0;     /* no flag */
printf("SUBITO PRIMA DELL'INIT\n");

   init();

   kid_pids = malloc(POP_SIZE*sizeof(*kid_pids));
   for (i=0; i<POP_SIZE; i++) {
       matricola = maxMin_rand(99999, 10000);
       //printf("\nSono qui3\n");
       switch (kid_pids[i] = fork()) {

       case -1:
           /* Handle error */
           TEST_ERROR;
           break;

       case 0:
           /* Wait for the green light */

           sops.sem_op = -1;
           semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);

           while(exit_loop == 0 || exit_loop == 1){


/*child code*/

               }

               unlockSem(sem_Id, ALUNNI);
               }
               //sleep(1);

           exit(0);
           break;

       default:
           break;
       }
   }

   /* 
    * All child  processes are  attached. Then the  shared memory
    * can be  marked for deletion.
    */

   while (shmctl(mem_Id, IPC_RMID, NULL)) { TEST_ERROR; }

   /* Inform child processes to start */

   sops.sem_op = POP_SIZE;
   semop(sem_Id, &sops, 1);


   /* Waiting for all child processes to terminate */
   while ((child_pid = wait(&status)) != -1) {
       dprintf(2,"PID=%d. Sender (PID=%d) terminated with status 0x%04X\n",
           getpid(),
           child_pid,
           status);

   }

   /* Now the semaphore may be deallocated */
   semctl(sem_Id, 0, IPC_RMID);
```

I expect to initialize the shared memory using the father process and create 15 children because the father got the LOCK on the semaphore PADRE. Then he Unlocks the Semaphore and it's the turn of the child. They interact with themselves updating the shared memory. After the timer expired, the father regain the LOCK, he prints some records of the shared memory, and finally terminates.

I must be using the semaphore wrong, maybe set a Semaphore for the father and another one for the Children is too much. If it can be fixed with just one Semaphore it's alright.

Comment: The approach you describe sounds questionable to me, but it's very difficult to make specific critiques without a representative [mcve].

Comment: That's all i wrote about semaphore, if anything is missing I'm sorry but I couldn't know.

Comment: Can I compile it myself, as-is? No, therefore it is not complete.  It's not even a whole function, there are calls to undefined functions, and there are uses of undefined macros.  If it were complete then the next question would be whether it reproduces the failure behavior you describe -- if not, then it would not be verifiable.  *Then* comes the question of whether it is minimal. It seems likely that some of the function calls are unnecessary for supporting the example, so probably not.  For a longer discourse on MCVEs, follow the link in my previous comment.